# Understanding quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces

Admittedly this will be probably be a naive question, but here it goes:

Is it possible to flesh out in simple terms, for someone with little background in group theory, what it means to take the quotient group of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ by a lattice $\Lambda$ or by $\mathbb Z$? How to evaluate this quotient? As in what comes out?

More precise examples:

- If $\Lambda$ is a lattice spanned by linearly independent primitive vectors $\mathbf{a}_1$ and $\mathbf{a}_2,$ then how to interpret the quotient: $\mathbb C /\Lambda?$
- Another example: the circle $S^1$ can be identified with the quotient $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z,$ but I fail to make this identification myself. Any help is much appreciated here.

Comment: Quotient groups are sets of cosets. So each all the elements of a coset represent the same element of the quotient (they are identified). So for $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, a coset may look like $1+2\pi\mathbb{Z}=\{\dotsc,1-2\pi,1,1+2\pi,\dotsc\}$, so all those values are identified. In particular, 0 and $2\pi$ are identified, but no two distinct points in the interior of that inverval are. And an interval with its endpoints identified is a circle.

Comment: @ziggurism hi, thanks for your comment. I didnt get what you meant by "identify" here. Would you be so kind and slighlty expand on your comment as an answer maybe? It would be very helpful. I also have to admit that I dont really know what cosets are. Thanks a lot in any case

Comment: A quotient of a set is a new set where you've simply decided that some elements of the original set are now forced to be the same element in the quotient. This is what I meant by "identify", and what @fly-by-night meant by "gluing". For example take the set $\{1,2,3\}$, you may decide to identify 1 and 3, so you get a new quotient set $\{1,2,3\}/\{1,3\} = \{1=3,2\}$. Note that a quotient set is not a subset of the original (subsets are in some sense dual to quotient sets).

Comment: You may take quotients of any set, but in group theory there is a standard construction. Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, you identify all elements of the group $G$ which differ by an element of the subgroup $H$. For example if the group is $\mathbb{R}$ and the subgroup is $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, then you identify the number 1 with the number $1+2\pi$ and $1+4\pi$ etc. In the quotient, the have only a single element $[1]=\{\dotsc,1-2\pi,1,1+2\pi,1+4\pi,\dotsc\}$. Sets like these are called cosets.

Comment: @ziggurism very helpful comments!! Thanks a lot, feel free to write it up as answer for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of a quotient as glueing things together. If you quotient out by $\Lambda$ then you consider every point that differs by an element of $\Lambda$ to be the same, i.e. glued together.

A simple example is modular arithmetic: $[0]_5=\{0, \pm 5, \pm 10, \pm 15\,\ldots\}$ are all the same, modulo five. They form the same residue class $[0]_5$. In terms of a quotient, this residue class is $\mathbb Z / 5\mathbb Z$.

In the case of $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ consider all points in $\mathbb C$, that differ only by an element of $\Lambda$, to be the same/glued. I assume your lattice is given by integer multiples of the complex numbers $u$ and $v$.
That means $\Lambda = \{\lambda u + \mu v : \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb Z \}$.

Let the elements of $\mathbb C$ that differ from $z \in \mathbb C$ by addition of an element of $\Lambda$ by $[z]$. We have
$$[z] = \{ z+ \lambda u + \mu v : \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb Z \}$$
In modular notation, $w \in [z]$ if, and only if, $w \equiv z \bmod \Lambda$.

The set $[z]$ forms a single element of the quotient $\mathbb C/\Lambda$. You'll After a while, you can convince yourself that $\mathbb C/\Lambda = \{ [\lambda u + \mu v] : 0 \le \lambda , \mu < 1 \}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the glueing picture is really helping me, neat! So is it correct to say that the result of $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$? I m slightly confused, arent all the points in C that differ from one another by an element of $\Lambda$, $\Lambda$ itself?

Comment: @user929304 Let $u=1$ and $v=\mathrm i$ then $\Lambda$ is all of the Gaussian integers $m+\mathrm i n$. All of these points make up the same equivalence class, so $[0] = \{m+\mathrm i n:m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$. But what about $\frac{1}{2}$? This does not belong to $[0]$, so we get a new equivalence class: $[\frac{1}{2}] = \{\frac{1}{2}+m+\mathrm i n:m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$. For any complex number $x+\mathrm i y$, where $0 \le x,y < 1$ we get different equivalence classes $[x+\mathrm i y]$.

Comment: @user929304 an easier example is $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$. Here we glue all points $\mathbb R$ that differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$. So $\{0, \pm 2\pi, \pm 4\pi, \ldots\}$ all get glues. So do $\{\varepsilon, \pm 2\pi+\varepsilon, \pm 4\pi+\varepsilon, \ldots\}$. You can think of it as rolling the real line up, like a role or (infinitely thin) wall/toilet paper, where the circumference of the role is $2\pi$. You get a circle.

Answer (score 2):

The quotient $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is a complex torus (see the picture for it on page $4$ [here](http://wstein.org/edu/2010/414/projects/raastad.pdf)); and the group is isomorphic to the group $E(\mathbb{C})$ of an elliptic curve $E$. The isomorphism is given by $(x,y)\mapsto (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$, for the Weierstrass $\wp$-function, with the elliptic curve equation
$$
\wp'(z)^2=4\wp(z)^3-g_2\wp(z)-g_3.
$$
Hence quotients $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$  are tori, and tori are elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is very terse for me, is it possible to explain it without employing elliptic curves?

Comment: Did the picture help you to see that the quotients $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ are tori ? This is enough for your first question.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It may help you to consider some examples of quotient groups that you are already comfortable in working with:

> $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$

The set of integers $\mathbb Z$ forms a group under addition. It contains a subgroup $n\mathbb Z=\{nk:k\in\mathbb Z\}$ consisting of the elements of $\mathbb Z$ that are divisible by $n$.

The quotient group is the set of cosets
$$\{n\mathbb Z, 1+n\mathbb Z, 2+n\mathbb Z,\ldots,(n-1)+n\mathbb Z\}$$
where $m+n\mathbb Z =\{m+nk:k\in\mathbb Z\}$, which is a group under the operation inherited from $\mathbb Z$:
$$(a+n\mathbb Z)+(b+n\mathbb Z) = (a+b)+n\mathbb Z$$
where you should notice that if $a+b\in n\mathbb Z$, then $(a+b)+n\mathbb Z = n\mathbb Z$.

This group is exactly the group of integers modulo $n$: write
$$a\equiv b\pmod n$$
if and only if $n\mid(b-a)$. Then the map sending $a+n\mathbb Z$ to $a\pmod n$ is an isomorphism.

> $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$

Let $[\cdot]:\mathbb R\to [0,1)$ be the map which sends a real number $x$ to its decimal part (e.g. $231.35642\mapsto 0.34642$).

If $x,y\in \mathbb R$, then it is easy to check that $$[x]+[y]=[x+y]$$
so that in particular, $[\cdot]$ defines a group structure on $[0,1)$.

You should check that with this group structure, $[0,1)\cong \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is therefore the group of real numbers where we consider two numbers as the same if they differ by an integer.

An important observation is that there is an isomorphism between $[0,1)$ and the unit circle in $S^1\subset\mathbb C^\times$ (both are groups under multiplication) given by
$$[0,1)\to S^1 \\ x\mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$$

So $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\cong S^1$, and can be viewed as a unit line in $\mathbb R$, where the two ends are glued together.

The quotient $\mathbb C/(\mathbb Z+\mathbb Zi)$ is a two-dimensional analgoue of this: it is a unit square in $\mathbb R^2$ with opposite sides glued together - or a torus $S^1\times S^1$

[image]

and $\mathbb C/\mathbb Z$ can be defined similarly for a general lattice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the examples! So to sanity check my thoughts, we know that given a lattice $\Lambda$ in Euclidean space $\mathbb R^d$, we can write the volume of the fundamental lattice cell as $\text{vol}(\mathbb R^d/\Lambda)$, because starting from any lattice point $x,$ the quotient group only keeps all the points between that lattice point $x$ and its neighbouring points, thus the measure of this set, should be the volume of the fundamental cell, about right?

Comment: That sounds right to me - and that volume will be $|\det(A)|$ where $A$ is a $d\times d$ matrix whose rows span the lattice.