# Understanding the meaning of $G$ modulo $H$

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition

I read the following definition: $G/H$ is the set of left cosets of $G$ modulo $H$ (Where $G$ and $H$ are groups).

Now, what  I don't understand is: what does  $G$ modulo $H$ mean?

Comment: Refers to the same thing.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1733675/285940

Comment: A quotient $G/H$ is the original set $G$ partitioned by an equivalence relation defined by the group $H$. That is: we says that $$p\sim q\iff p\in q\odot H$$ for all $p,q\in G$, where $\odot$ is the group operation in $G$.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69050/11619).

Answer (score 1):

It means the group of elements of $G$ collected together by whether they differ by an element of $H$; in effect, it generalises the notion  of integers modulo some number $n$, since, in that case, one considers the integers in equivalence classes according to how they differ by a multiple of $n$.